# How to have a Onload event with Vuejs - specifically how to put the script in the method and the way to get a call in the html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods

```
export default {

    methods: {
    hotbod() { document.querySelector("body")},

    doStuff() {
      hotbod.className += " animate";
    },


    window:onload = function() {
      doStuff();
    },
      },
    }
```

Above is the code, that I think has some errors in it - and for some reason I cannot get the javascript to work (On page load, there are CSS that gets loaded).

Answer (score 4):

To launch a component method on the window's load, simply add the load listener in your mounted() hook. For example:

```
mounted(){
    window.addEventListener("load", () => this.processLoad());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a method upon the emission of the window `onload` event, simply use a relevant [Vue lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) to attach the event listener. For example:

```
export default {
    create() {
        window.addEventListener("load", this.onWindowLoad);
    },
    methods: {
        onWindowLoad() {
            console.log("window load event");
        },
    },
};
```

Instead of `created`, you might also use `beforeCreate`, `beforeMount`, or `mounted`. I don't think there's functionally a difference in this case.

You also may want to detach the listener upon the component's destruction (hooks `beforeDestroy` and `destroy`), though in practice, because it's only firing once, it may not matter.

Also note that, for reasons of scope, if you use an anonymous callback function, it must be an arrow function.

Comment: Hm, using this was causing a ReferenceError regarding "window" on compiling Vue.js in my case.

Comment: it causes a RefrenceError